# oracle sql trigger compile

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: 1]

when I do practice by oracle sql plus, I try to write a trigger but it cant compile. I don't know why please help me

[image: 2]

"location" is the column name, it should get result brisbane50

Comment: Please, [do not post images of code, data and error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557). Post it as a plain text. The error is because `dual` has no `location` column. You may check the error by issuing `show errors` command in SQL*Plus after trigger creation or `select * from user_errors`.

Comment: Additionally, you are adding an unnecessary context switch.  Just assign `:NEW.DEPTNO` via `:=` rather than `SELECT` from dual;

Comment: You probably just want `:NEW.DEPTNO := :NEW.LOCATION || DEPTNO_SEQ.NEXTVAL;`

Comment: The pictures you've included have a text rendering that is difficult to read. Its font combined with its background is terrible. Pasting text makes it possible for the site to offer a much better, easier to read rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Just after your trigger creation (IE : after the `/`) add:

`SHOW ERRORS;`

This will display your trigger error.
My bet is the " in the table names.
Just remove them.